# Помогите найти API геокодера

Tags: javascript, api, rest, геолокация, location

Есть ли такое API, которое по *названию города/коду страны/координатам города* вернет мне название страны
**на русском языке**?

Answer (score 0):

Помог API : https://opencagedata.com/api
Можно определить страну города, если ввести его координаты